# Generate HTML from Spring MVC Form

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I'm new to Spring and I'm looking for some way for generating HTML output from Spring <s>from</s> form class? Is there similar method as in [Django forms](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#outputting-forms-as-html)

Than you!

Answer (score 0):

For automated generation of forms (and backing beans, models and the whole application), have a look at [Spring Roo](http://projects.spring.io/spring-roo/).

Comment: thank you for your reply...  but I`m looking for creating forms from model object not for baking "html template"... I thing that spring root just baking my app. Many thanks for another solution